# Custom Component Properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I made a custom component that inherits TextBox. I gave the component a property called "Watermark". The property accessible in the Properties window after dragging one of these components from the toolbox. However, if I assign a value to Watermark, it doesn't carry over to when i have the program launched.

```
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Extended Properties")]
[Description("Set TextBox's watermark")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public string Watermark
{
    get; set;
}

public TextBoxWithWatermark()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeWatermark();
}

public TextBoxWithWatermark(IContainer container)
{
    container.Add(this);
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeWatermark();
}

private void InitializeWatermark()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Watermark: " + Watermark);
    Text = Watermark;
}
```

The Console#WriteLine claims that its blank no matter what. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: assign `Text` in `Watermark`. **Set**

Comment: I don't understand how setting Text to Watermark would do what I am asking about. :/ I'm trying to figure out how to make "Watermark" carry whatever value that is assigned from the property window.

Comment: use `get {return watermark;} set(value){Text = value; watermark = value}` , instead of just `get;set;`

Comment: Wow that was it. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lei Yang in the comments, it's solved.

I had to change to this..

```
    private string watermark;
    public string Watermark
    {
        get
        {
            return watermark;
        }
        set
        {
            Text = value;
            watermark = value;
        }
    }
```